# Ember - Cli , Rails API JSON API FORMAT , AMS 0.10.0 rc Not Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ember.js

I am stuck with the JSON API , AMS, RAILS combination....

I covered ember with some books like "Rock and Roll with ember js" , "Ember-cli -101"
But here is a scenario where i need to put some has_many / belongs_to relationship with some data...

In My Ember Application

models/customer.js

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  contactname: DS.attr('string'),
  contactno: DS.attr('string'),
  othcontactno: DS.attr('string'),
  othrefdetails: DS.attr('string'),
  projects: DS.hasMany('project'),
});
```

models/project.js

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  customer: DS.belongsTo('customer' , {async:true}),
  agent: DS.belongsTo('agent' , {async:true})
});
```

adapters/application.js

```
export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
  host: 'http://localhost:3000',
  shouldReloadRecord(store, snapshot) {
    return false;
  },
});
```

serializers/applicaiton.js

```
 export default DS.JSONAPISerializer.extend({
 });
```

And in my Rails api

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :enquiries
  resources :agents
  resources :customers
  resources :projects
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :customer 
   #belongs_to :agent
   #has_many :enquiries
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :customer
end


class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :projects
   accepts_nested_attributes_for :projects
end



class ProjectSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name
   belongs_to :customer
   #has_one :agent
   #has_many :enquiries
end


class CustomerSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :contactname, :contactno, :othcontactno, :othrefdetails
    has_many :projects
end
```

initializers/json_api.rb

```
ActiveModel::Serializer.config.adapter = ActiveModel::Serializer::Adapter::JsonApi
```

Gem File (I am using 0.10.0 rc3 due to some bugs in 0.9 version)

```
gem 'active_model_serializers' , '~> 0.10.0.rc3'
 # gem 'active_model_serializers' , '~> 0.9.3'
```

I am getting a json response for localhost:3000/customers From The rails api like this

```
{"data":[{"id":"6","type":"customers","attributes":{"name":"Talhaqqq","contactname":"Mohammed Talha","contactno":"9744878171","othcontactno":"+9104735253585","othrefdetails":"nil"},"relationships":{"projects":{"data":[{"id":"1","type":"projects"}]}}},{"id":"10","type":"customers","attributes":{"name":"Ameer Ali qq","contactname":"Ameer Mohammed Ali","contactno":"234234","othcontactno":"439870987","othrefdetails":"othr ref detaila"},"relationships":{"projects":{"data":[]}}},{"id":"67","type":"customers","attributes":{"name":"Signlab qqq","contactname":"Sigblab contact","contactno":"2340987","othcontactno":"sjfdla98","othrefdetails":"s098-"},"relationships":{"projects":{"data":[{"id":"2","type":"projects"}]}}},{"id":"68","type":"customers","attributes":{"name":"Anwar Nazar","contactname":"Anwar","contactno":"2+87+968","othcontactno":"354+641+9","othrefdetails":"31651651"},"relationships":{"projects":{"data":[]}}},{"id":"69","type":"customers","attributes":{"name":"Cust name qqq","contactname":"asdfda","contactno":"sdfsdf","othcontactno":"sadfafd","othrefdetails":"asfdgadfg"},"relationships":{"projects":{"data":[]}}},{"id":"70","type":"customers","attributes":{"name":"dsasva","contactname":"a","contactno":"sdfvsfva","othcontactno":"asdv","othrefdetails":"vafasdfv"},"relationships":{"projects":{"data":[]}}},{"id":"71","type":"customers","attributes":{"name":"egrweg","contactname":"aevg","contactno":"asdgr","othcontactno":"aergarg","othrefdetails":"saerg"},"relationships":{"projects":{"data":[]}}}]}
```

I am trying to set a customer for a project....

I tried it manually in one of the routes actions.... (I dont know the best way to do it in ember ).. Both of the tutorial books is not giving me a best way to set the relationship data

```
let project = this.store.peekRecord('project', 3);
let customer = this.store.peekRecord('customer', 6);
project.set('customer', customer ); 
project.save();
```

And i am getting this on rails

```
  Parameters: {"data"=>{"id"=>"3", "attributes"=>{"name"=>"Xyy project"}, "relationships"=>{"customer"=>{"data"=>{"type"=>"customers", "id"=>"6"}}}, "type"=>"projects"}, "id"=>"3"}
```

I tried to permit the relationships, attributes in Projects_controller

```
params.require(:data).permit!
#  params.require(:data)
# .permit(:id ,   :attributes => [:name] , :relationships => [:customer => [:data] =>[:type] ] , :customer => [:data] )
```

But nothing worked well .. always given unpermitted parameter... and i ended up permitting all params using

```
params.require(:data).permit!
```

And finally , When i did the update using this function

```
  def update
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @customer = Customer.find(6)
    @project.update_attributes(:customer => params[:customer])
    if @project.update(project_params)

      head :no_content
    else
      render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

I got this response in rails customer_id = NULL..

```
Started PATCH "/projects/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-12-09 09:32:42 +0530
Processing by ProjectsController#update as JSON
  Parameters: {"data"=>{"id"=>"1", "attributes"=>{"name"=>"Lulu Mall Project qw "}, "relationships"=>{"customer"=>{"data"=>{"type"=>"customers", "id"=>"67"}}}, "type"=>"projects"}, "id"=>"1"}
  Project Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  `projects`.* FROM `projects` WHERE `projects`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  `projects`.* FROM `projects` WHERE `projects`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
  Customer Load (0.9ms)  SELECT  `customers`.* FROM `customers` WHERE `customers`.`id` = 6 LIMIT 1
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  SQL (1.1ms)  UPDATE `projects` SET `customer_id` = NULL, `updated_at` = '2015-12-09 04:02:42' WHERE `projects`.`id` = 1
   (50.4ms)  COMMIT

{"data"=>{"id"=>"1", "attributes"=>{"name"=>"Lulu Mall Project qw "}, "relationships"=>{"customer"=>{"data"=>{"type"=>"customers", "id"=>"67"}}}, "type"=>"projects"}, "controller"=>"projects", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"1"}
   (0.8ms)  BEGIN
```

I know i am totally confused,, I tried to use AMS 0.9 version without the JSON API Standard , but ended up in stack level too deep error and come other problems.

But using the AMS 0.10.0 rc version and standard JSON API Format, i couldn't find any tutorials or answers for these questions..

1. How to set relationship data in ember ?
2. The best json format from API (standart json / json with embed ids )?
3. How to allow strong parametes in Rails (Especially nested with relationships{id, type} etc...  With STANDARD JSON API FORMAT)?
4. Update relationship (update attributes ) in Rails with the json api request from ember?
5. Is it best to go with the JSON API FORMAT , and AMS ...AND JSON API ADAPTER /SERIALIZER...

It feels some thing like an eclipse should happen with these things to work all together...